# looking for a debug feature in C

Tags: c, debugging, memory

I believe my code has some memory bugs, because my code acts "randomly" in the sense that in almost every run some, a string in a large fixed array is being corrupted. (Fixed, in the sense that it should always be the same. But the problem occurs while I'm initializing its values.)

I wonder, if there is a debugger with a feature that would enable me to run the same code in parallel and alert me once there is difference between the two runs?

(I work on linux, my project is in C, and I'm currently debugging with GDB. I've tried running valgrind but I have too much memory not being freed in edge cases.)

Comment: Instead of comparing two runs (probably not supported) why not just set a breakpoint on any write to the large array?

Comment: There is a technique called 'delta debugging' which addresses this scenario.  I don't know if it has been productized.

Comment: @Jerry- i have clarified what i meant by fixed above. and actually i have simplified things quite much in the question, so the problem really is somewhere between reading a line from a file and parsing it.

Comment: you coudld try valgrind on a machine with more memory...or perhaps run on a smaller 'test' data set?

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but:  int i = 1; while(i>0){i*=2;} printf(%d, i);  (forgive the syntax, my C is rusty).  So, both values and indeces can only be referenced by the above i.  If your data structures are larder than the above i's, you're in trouble.  Interesting problem, good luck!

Comment: ok, so I just read your comment, how many characters are in your lines?  Perhaps, try chomping them a bit?

Comment: if this is unclear, sooner or later the sign bit swaps, the sign bit is the most significant bit, and hilarity ensues.

Comment: Just post the problematic code, let the inspection begin.....

Comment: @Dale - i'm afraid i dont realy understand your suggestion.. all the string are very short(about 10 chars).

Comment: @Mellowcandle- i can shorten it to 500~ lines of relevent code.. should i still post it? if so, can i post it in a way that it wont cover the whole screen?

Comment: Like I said, I wasn't sure if my suggestion would be helpful or not.  To me, the first thing that came to mind was random sign flippage somewhere.  Probably not, apparently.

Comment: That being said, if you are using ints in your code, make sure they dont flip over.

Comment: Watchpoints... After you initialize for the first time, you put a watchpoint on e.g. `somestring[12] != 'x'` or something simlar. The when `somestring[12]` changes the debugger will break.

Comment: you said you believe that your code has memory bug. Thats a rather ambiguous statement. valgrind with suitable switches can uncover every heap related error. What you should do is to play with valgrind --tool=memcheck with different switches. If your code has problem in statically allocated spaces (both on global storage or in stack) then the best solution is to use gdb with hardware watchpoint.

Answer (score 0):

A good start is to run your application under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and see what it report.